# Is possible to record MIDI via USB from a roll up piano?

Tags: sound, usb, midi

I have a roll up piano (see the image) that has an USB output.

> [image]

An USB cable comes with it: it is able to connect the roll up piano with the computer.

> [image]

Is there any way to record MIDI using the roll up piano, the USB cable and the computer (that runs Ubuntu)? Is a MIDI cable really required if I have the USB one?

What are the steps to record MIDI on Ubuntu using the roll up piano and the USB cable?

The output of `arecordmidi -l`:

```
# no cable is connected (after fresh restart)
$ arecordmidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0

# USB only
$ arecordmidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 24:0    USB MIDI Interface               USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1

# MIDI only
$ arecordmidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0

# USB & MIDI
$ arecordmidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 24:0    USB MIDI Interface               USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1
```

I tried to use QJackCtl and some other applications to make the connections:

> [image]

Comment: What is the output of `arecordmidi -l`?

Comment: @CL. I bought a MIDI cable. Please see the edit.

Comment: Does `aseqdump -p 20:0` show anything? If yes, just run a sequencer.

Comment: @CL. No... Just `Waiting for data. Press Ctrl+C to end.`, but no output when pressing the keys. Hey, are you Clemens Ladisch, the creator of `arecordmidi`? :-) If you solve my problem, I will give you more points! :-D

Comment: Did you connect the keyboard's output to the interface's input? Why aren't you just using the USB cable?

Comment: @CL. Yes, I did... I tried both: with 20 and 14 but it doesn't work...

Comment: What is the output of `arecordmidi -l` with the USB cable?

Comment: @CL. `20:0    USB MIDI Interface               USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1`, I guess. `14:0` is used for the MIDI cable and `20:0` is for USB cable. Only Port values are sometimes changed.

Comment: I meant when you connect the keyboard directly, without the USB/MIDI interface. (14:0 is not an hardware port.)

Comment: @CL. I updated my question with relevant output information.

Comment: What exactly did you do in the "MIDI" cases (where nothing is happening)?

Comment: @CL. `MIDI only` = connected the piano roll via MIDI cable only (tried the both ways: OUT and IN jacks ) with the laptop (USB). `USB & MIDI` = connected the two cables the same time. I also noticed that `Midi Throug` client is present always.

Comment: "Midi Through" is an internal loopback that has nothing to do with your hardware. I don't know why nothing comes over the USB cable; maybe the keyboard must be configured somehow? Is there a manual? The MIDI cable appears to be broken; try to plug it into another (even Windows) computer.

Comment: @CL. It has a manual, but I can't find anything related to MIDI. Is there any way for debugging? Maybe a verbose parameter?

Comment: All that aseqdump stuff *is* the way for debugging. To rule out a (software/hardware) problem with your PC, try with another PC.

Comment: Can help You. [Drum Roll Up as midi](https://code.google.com/p/drumroll/)

Comment: @CL. I feel that we are a little bit closer to the solution. See the screenshot from edited question. However, I still not receive any data in `aseqdump`...

Comment: Nothing new there. If the piano doesn't show up when connected with its USB cable, it's likely that it is broken.

Comment: @CL. I bought another midi cable for another project. This adapter has 2 MIDI inputs with two corresponding LEDs. When I connect it to the roll up piano, and press the keys, the corresponding LED turns on. However, still no output from `aseqdump`. Since the LED turns on I believe that some data is sent from the roll up piano, but I am not sure where it stops. Is there another way to get _raw_ data from the adapter assuming that it sends something but not parsable by `aseqdump`?

Comment: To see raw data, use `amidi --dump` with the appropriate port.

Comment: @CL. Just tried it. Nothing arrives... However, what would be the explanation why the LED of the midi adapter is turning on when I press the keys?

Comment: Apparently, the LED shows that *something* is happening on the port. If the adapter works with other MIDI devices, then the problem is with the piano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of program that allows you to record MIDI data is called a [sequencer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_audio_software#Recording.2C_editing_and_mastering); try Rosegarden, Seq24, or Qtractor.

Your piano can be connected with either the USB cable or a MIDI cable.